# How do I make n-amount of inputs in a for-loop and use all the inputs later?

Tags: python, loops

Here there are a "num" amount of inputs. How do I get the nth input value?

```
num = input("How many values?")

for x in range(0, int(num)):
    ok = input()
```

Comment: Try `values = [input() for _  in range(num)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store inputs in list.

```
num = input("How many values?")
ok=[]
for x in range(0, int(num)):
    ok.append(input())
print(ok)
```

And for nth value:

```
ans = ok[n-1]
```